# Copy excel autofiltered table to outlook email in vba

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to copy excel filtered table to email using the famous **RangetoHTML function** by Ron de Bruin, my original code **use a for loop to autofilter the table based on a list I created** and tried to copy this filtered table to each email address I wish to send, however the content of emailbody is always a "?"
Wonder if anyone could help me take a look at the code as what's wrong?

```
Sub create_email_table()

Dim count_col As Integer
Dim count_row As Integer
Dim og As Worksheet
Dim list As Worksheet
Dim ism As String
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set og = Worksheets("ISM") 'the full sheet
Set list = Worksheets("ISM Email") 'the list I use to filter the datasheet


og.Activate

count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))


list.Activate
Count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))


For i = 1 To Count

'updating the team
ism = list.Cells(i, 1).Text

og.AutoFilterMode = False      'turn off prior filters

og.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=ism

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = og.Range("A1:B1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Dim dam As Object
  
    Set dam = CreateObject("outlook.application").createitem(0)
    dam.To = list.Cells(i, 1).Value
    dam.Subject = "Reminder of no record in system "
    dam.HTMLbody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    dam.Display
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
og.ShowAllData
og.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Above is my for loop to autofilter the sheet and send each recipient the filtered table, below is the RangeTohtml function

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `RangetoHTML` isn't working in this case... but my guess would be that it has to do with the fact that the visible cells of an AutoFiltered table are a noncontiguous range.

I would suggest using the Word object model to copy-paste the filtered table into an Outlook mail item instead. Here is a function that will do that for you:

```
Public Function ExcelRangeToOutlookEmailBody(Rng As Range) As Object
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Sh As Worksheet
    Dim OlkApp As Object, OlkMsg As Object, OlkInsp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
   
    Set Sh = Rng.Parent
    Set Wb = Sh.Parent
    Rng.Copy
   
    Set OlkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlkMsg = OlkApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set OlkInsp = OlkMsg.GetInspector
   
    If OlkInsp.EditorType = 4 Then
        Set WordDoc = OlkInsp.WordEditor
        WordDoc.Content.PasteAndFormat 16
    End If
   
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set ExcelRangeToOutlookEmailBody = OlkMsg
    Set OlkApp = Nothing
End Function
```

The argument `Rng` is the cell range you want to insert into the email. The function returns the Outlook `MailItem` object into whose body the cells were pasted. Call it & save the return value in an object, to do other stuff to the email like set the To / subject fields, display it, or send it.

Using the Word object model to copy Excel cells into Outlook is very "what you see is what you get". This has a lot of advantages. If you copy an entire auto-filtered range, it will only paste the visible values--no need to select them specifically. It will even paste any Pictures, Charts, or other Shapes that are in the selection area!

Here is a general idea of how you might use this function for your specific task:

```
Sub MakeEmailForEachAutoFilterValue()
    Dim DataWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim FilterWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim FilterColumn As Long
    Dim FilterCell As Range
    Dim OutlookMsg As Object
   
    Set DataWorksheet = Worksheets("ISM")
    Set FilterWorksheet = Worksheets("ISM Email")
    FilterColumn = 5
   
    For Each FilterCell In FilterWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        DataWorksheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:=FilterCell.Value
        Set OutlookMsg = ExcelRangeToOutlookEmailBody(DataWorksheet.UsedRange)
        OutlookMsg.Subject = "Reminder of no record in system"
        OutlookMsg.Display
    Next FilterCell
End Sub
```

The above Sub will loop over each cell in the first column of "ISM Email", apply that cell's value as an AutoFilter on column E (i.e. 5) of "ISM", and generate a new email with a table of the AutoFiltered data in its body.